# How can I have different cross axis alignments for different rows in Flutter column while keeping the width to a minimum?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make this:

[image: chat preview]

but with the timestamp on the right.

Currently I have (simplified for reading purposes but the essence is there):

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(name),
    Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
      child: Text(content),
    ),
    Text(
      timestamp,
    ),
  ],
);
```

So the name needs to be aligned on the left side, the content *determines* the width of the column with a maximum of 200, and the timestamp should be on the right side.

The problem here is that I cannot use anything like using a row with `Expanded` or `Spacer` or a regular container with max width and then the right alignment or anything else because they will all take as much horizontal space as possible, while I want to take as little space as possible while letting the length of content determine the width. Setting `crossaxisalignment` to  `CrossAxisAlignment.end` fixes it but then the name is on the wrong side of course.

So essentially I want a different `crossaxisalignment` for different elements in the column, or at least something to that effect. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after experimenting a bit.

It was no more difficult than wrapping the `Column` with `ÌntrinsicWidth` and then simply setting the alignment in the `Text`. Everything else remains the same.